# Create fast user login and data verification using JavaEE with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee

Create fast user login and data verification using JavaEE with MongoDB

Problem : How to create fast user login and signup verification using Java EE with MongoDB ?

```
        Signup approach
```

> User.java POJO class

```
packgae app.name;

public final class User implements Serializable{

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private String fullName, email, mobileNumber, password;
       private static final User USER_INSTANCE = new User();

       private User(){

       }

       public static User getInstance(){
             return USER_INSTANCE;
       }           

       // setters and getters omitted
}
```

> MongoDB configuration

DBConfig.java

```
package app.name.db;

//all mongodb import declarations

   public final class DBConfig{

    private final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DBConfig.class.getName());
    private final String HOST = "localhost";
    private final int PORT = 27017;
    private final String DATABASENAME = "simpleuser";

    private static final DBConfiguration INSTANCE = new DBConfiguration();


    public DBConfiguration(){
    }

    public static DBConfiguration newInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    //@Produces
    public MongoClient connect() {
            try {
            return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(HOST, PORT));

        } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        closeDBConnection();
            return null;    
    }

    public void closeDBConnection(){
        connect().close();
        }

}
```

> UserDB.java

```
package app.name.db.signup;

import app.name.User;
// all other necessary import declaration


public class UserDB {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserDB.class.getName());

   private DBConfig dbconfig = DBConfig.newInstance();

   public void create(User user) {

      MongoCollection<Document> collection = dbconfig.accessCollection("users");

      if  (user != null) {
         Document userDatabase = new Document().append( "signudate", "signup date method here" )   
            .append( "fullname", user.getFullName() )
        .append( "email", user.getEmail() )
        .append( "mobilenumber", user.getMobileNumber() )
            .append( "password", user.getPassword() );
         collection.insertOne(userDatabase);
      }
   }
```

> UserSignup.java

```
package app.name.db.signup;

import app.name.User;
import app.name.db.*;

// all other necessary import declaration



@Named("userSignup")
@SessionScoped

public class UserSignup implements Serializable {

   private User user = User.getInstance();

   @EJB
   private UserDB userDB;

   public UserSignup() {
   }

   @PostConstruct
   private void init() {
   }

   public void create() {
      userDB.create(user);
   }

   // Necessary getters and setters here
}
```

welcome.xhtml (.xhtml was removed using omnifaces dependency )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" >


<ui:composition template="index.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="signup">


 <f:ajax disabled="false" execute="@all" onerror="@all" render="submit" onevent="submit">
                                            <h:form  method="post"  >


            <input jsf:id="fullname" type="text" placeholder="Fullname" required="true" requiredMessage="Full name is required" validatorMessage="Ensure your Full name appears like this(James Gosling)" value="#{userSignup.user.fullName}" maxlength="21">
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="regex pattern here" for="fullname" />
                        </input><h:message for="fullname" style="color:red"/>


... Follwed with other input field

                       <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Register" action="welcome_page_ensure_data verification"/> 


  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

REMARK #1 : This works as expected, but I smell minor loading and poor performance;

QUESTION #1 : What is the best way to improve this ?

```
        Login Approach
```

> UserLogin.java

```
package app.name.db.login;


@Named("verifyandlogin")
@SessionScoped

public class UserLogin implements Serializable  {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserLogin.class.getName());
   private DBConfiguration dbconfig = DBConfiguration.newInstance();
   private String otp; // assuming that username is sent to user mail inform of OTP

   private static final UserLogin LOGIN_USER_INSTANCE = new UserLogin();

   private UserLogin(){

   }

   public static UserLogin getLoginInstance(){
    return LOGIN_USER_INSTANCE;
   }

   public LoginStaff loginStaff(){
        return new LoginStaff();
   }

   // setters and getters here


   public DBObject isOTPValid(String otpInput) {

    BasicDBObject query = DBConfiguration.newBasicDBObjectInstance( "otp",otpInput ); 

        // This will access the dbname/collection/document example /simpleuser/user/otp
    // As stated, otp column will be created automatically with random value when user sign up succesfully

    BasicDBObject projection = DBConfiguration.newBasicDBObjectInstance("fullname", 1);
    // This will access the dbname/collection/document example /simpleuser/user/

    projection.append("email", 1)
          .append("mobilenumber",1);

    DBObject result = dbconfig.connectDBToCollection("simpleuser","users").findOne(query, projection);
    dbconfig.closeDBConnection();

    return result;
   }

   // So, what is the above method used for ?

    /*
        1.To take the user input on login page
            2.Verify is OTP is valid
        3.If valid, login the user in, if not ( let the user keep trying )

     */

      public User myStaff(String input){

    dbconfig.closeDBConnection();

    final String fullname = String.format( (String) isOTPValid( getOtp() ).get("fullname") ); 
    final String email = String.format( (String) isOTPValid( getOtp() ).get("email") ); 
    final String mobileNumber = String.format( (String) isOTPValid( getOtp() ).get("mobilenumber") ); 


    return User.newInstances(fullname, email, mobileNumber); 
  }

       // So, what is the above method also used for ?

    /*
        1.Once user OTP is verified succesfully
            2.Other app pages access the user's data ( fullname, email ...)

     */

}

welcome.xhtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets" >


<ui:composition template="index.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="login">


                                            <h:form  method="post"  >


            <input jsf:id="otp" type="text" placeholder="OTP key" required="true" requiredMessage="OTP is a must" validatorMessage="Ensure your OTP is correct or request for new OTP" value="#{verifyandlogin.otp}" maxlength="15">
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="regex pattern here" for="otp" />
                        </input><h:message for="otp" style="color:red"/>

                       <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" action="welcomepage"/> 
</h:form>

  </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

REMARK #2 : This works as expected, poor performance

```
    The following was observed

    1. Extremely poor performance and lazy loading 
    2. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached when multiple test is done;
```

QUESTION #2 : What is the best way to improve this ? Improve What ?

```
    Ensure fast user login and signup using Java EE with MongoDB ?
```

Thanks.